# want SELECT to return multiple values in a single row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table structure like that:

```
id     int     primary key
name   varchar 
start_time float
```

the data may be like that:

```
id    name      start_time
1     tt1          20.3
2     tt3          19.5
3     tt1          23.1
4     tt1          40.1
5     tt4          20.5
6     tt3          44.2
```

I want the result set grouped by name and list all start_time in the each group like that:

```
name       start_times
tt1      (20.3,23.1,40.1)
tt3      (19.5,44.2)
tt4      (20.5)
```

And the order of the result set is the number of start_time in each group.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) FUNCTION.

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(start_time ORDER BY start_time) AS start_times
FROM your_table GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(start_time)
```

Comment: don't forget `order by COUNT(start_time)`